# How to convert from string stored yyyymmdd format to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a date that is stored as a string and I want to convert or cast it from `varchar` to `date`. It is stored as `yyyymmdd` in string. The date output should be in `yyyymmdd` format, `date` data type:

```
DECLARE @UntilRule nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @UntilDate date

SET @UntilRule = 20200601
SET @UntilDate = FORMAT(CAST(SUBSTRING(@UntilRule, CHARINDEX('=', @UntilRule) + 1, 8) AS date), 'yyyymmdd')
```

I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Did you over-simplify your example? Perhaps **vastly**? Why do you need that complex expression to convert a simple string (as demonstrated by Gordon)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

```
select convert(date, @UntilRule)
```

Your format is the SQL Server standard for dates.